# tensorflow retrain model file

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

im getting started with tensorflow und using retrain.py to teach it some new categories - this works well - however i have some questions:

In the comments of retrain.py it says: 
"This produces a new model file that can be loaded and run by any TensorFlow
program, for example the label_image sample code"
however I havent found where this new model file is saved to ?

also: it does contain the whole model, right ? not just the retrained part  ?

Thanks for clearing this up

Comment: Please share some code if you want someone to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)I think you may want to save the new model.
When you want to save a model after some process, you can use 
`saver.save(sess, 'directory/model-name', *optional-arg)`.

Check out https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver

If you change model-name by epoch or any measure you would like to use, you can save the new model(otherwise, it may overlap with previous models saved).

You can find the model saved by searching 'checkpoint', '.index', '.meta'.

2)Saving the whole model or just part of it?
It's the part you need to learn bunch of ideas on tf.session and savers. You can save either the whole or just part, it's up to you. Again, start from the above link. The moral is that you put the variables you would like to save in a list quoted as 'var_list' in the link, and you can save only for them. When you call them back, you now also need to specify which variables in your model correspond to the variables in the loaded variables.

Answer (score 0):

While running retrain.py you can give --output_graph and --output_labels parameters which specify the location to save graph (default is /tmp/output_graph.pb) and the labels as well. You can change those as per your requirements.